# Shiny: Create a dynamic datatable based on a click event on another datatable

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, reactive

I'm Creating a shiny app with reactive values where when I select a row,
1.) it will fetch the node and
2.) find all the route associated that node in whole dataframe
3.) filter original df by above route selected.

```
df <- data.frame("Route" = c("R2","R2","R2","R3","R2","R1","R2","R3","R1"),
             "Nodes" = c("N1","N2","N2","N3","N2","N1","N3","N3","N2"),
             "X1" = c(81,65,61,64,59,51,69,95,99),
             "X2" = c(7,8,15,1,5,10,4,7,8))


 library(shiny)
 library(shinydashboard)
 library(DT)



 ui <- dashboardPage(
 dashboardHeader(title = "Dynamic Table"),
 dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenu(menuItem("Route", tabName = "tab_01"))),
 dashboardBody(tabItems(
 tabItem(tabName = "tab_01",
        tabsetPanel(
          tabPanel("T1", DT::DTOutput("table_01")),
          tabPanel("T2", DT::DTOutput("table_02"))
        )
        )))
 )


server <- function(input, output){
output$table_01 <- renderDT(datatable(data = df, selection = "single"))




output$table_02 <- renderDT(datatable({
s=input$table_01_rows_selected
n <- unique(df[s,c("Nodes")])
data = df[df$Nodes %in% n,]
}))

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

So basically if I select row no 4, i.e node "N3". route associated with "N3" are "R2" and "R3". Lastly I have to filter all the routes which have either "R2" and "R3" in df.

Comment: In your current app you click on a row in Tab 1 and In Tab 2 you can see all the rows with the same `Node`. So you also want to filter the table in Tab1 to only show the routes corresponding to tho the table in Tab 2? For now it's a bit unclear what your asking.

Comment: I had shared my worked data.  I'm not very clear how to use Reactivity expression.

Comment: What reactive expression? Do you want a third table with the filtered routes?

Comment: @WilmarvanOmmeren My aim is to select a row from tab1, store its  _node_  value , then find all the _route_  that are linked with store _node_ value, In tab 2 I would like to show only those observation having route id that we found by linked with node.   

#   c(N = N1)   
## c(R1, R2) linked with N1    #### to show in table, direct filter of original df containing R1 and R2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
output$table_02 <- renderDT({
    #  selected row from tab1
    selected_row=input$table_01_rows_selected
    # store its node value
    node <- unique(df[selected_row, "Nodes"])
    # find all the routes that are linked with the stored node value
    routes =  df[df$Nodes %in% node,]
    # show only those observation having the route id that we found in the previous step
    datatable(
      df[df$Route %in% routes$Route,]
    )
  })
```